# addComponent(index, cmp) in Codenameone is not respecting the index

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

I am using addComponent(index, cmp), then revalidating the container where I add the cmp to, but cmp is always added to the bottom of the container (last item of the container components) - it's not respecting the index. Any ideas??

```
otherLabel is a codenameone label
otherField is a codenameone textfield
Container7 is a container with 14 components

findContainer7().addComponent(8,otherLabel);
findContainer7().addComponent(9,otherField);
findContainer7().revalidate();
```

After this point, otherLabel and otherField will be display in the UI last in the container (index 13,14)

Answer (score 0):

The index only matters for some layout managers. Since you didn't mention the layout manager I guess you picked table layout where index isn't relevant since its a constraint based layout.